# Render error with simple_form on remote true form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to render an error on my form with Ajax if a validation is not verified. Unfortunately, my form is rendered again but there is no alert appearing for the error. Can you help me to figure why ?

**_concours_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @waiting_user, {id: 'concours-form', url: concours_path, remote: true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email,
      class: "landing-form-input",
      autocomplete: "off",
      required: true,
      pattern: '[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}',
      placeholder: "Renseignez ton email ici"
    %>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
  <%= f.hidden_field :concours_city,
      value:'',
      id: 'c-choosen-city'
    %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :source,
      value: params[:source]
    %>
  <%= f.button :submit,
      class: "landing-form-button",
      value: "Je tente ma chance !"
    %>
<% end %>
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
def create_concours
    @email = waiting_list_params[:email]
    @waiting_user = WaitingList.new(waiting_list_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @waiting_user.save
        UserMailer.welcome(@email).deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to concours_path }
        format.js
      else
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def waiting_list_params
    params.require(:waiting_list).permit(:email, :concours_city, :source)
  end
```

**create_concours.js.erb**

```
<% if @waiting_user.errors.any? %>
  refreshForm('<%= j render "pages/concours_form" %>');
<% end %>
```

Comment: In your controller you need to make it look something like this - `format.js {  flash[:error] = @waiting_user.errors.full_messages  }` and in your view `js.erb`, you should have `$("#show_error").html("<%= flash[:error] %>");`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is `#show_error`? Should I put `$("#show_error").html("<%= flash[:error] %>");` in the `<% if @waiting_user.errors.any? %>`?

Comment: `#show_error` is the `div` which I assumed to show the error in your page(it could be a section b/w header and body of the form.). And yes you need to put `$("#show_error").html("<%= flash[:error] %>")` inside the condition.

Comment: Thanks, I can make the error appear now. But if I submit the form a second time with a good value, it doesn't disappear, do you know why?

Comment: create_concours.js.erb `<% if @waiting_user.errors.any? %>
  err.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert"><%= flash[:error] %></div>');
  refreshForm('<%= j render "pages/concours_form" %>');
<% else %>
  err.innerHTML = ""
<% end %>`

Comment: It works for the first try but it's like create_concours.js.erb is not called a second time after the second submit

Comment: Can you check your logs and see, the 2nd time if `create.js.erb` is rendered?

Comment: It is ! `Rendering pages/create_concours.js.erb
  Rendered pages/_concours_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered pages/create_concours.js.erb (5.8ms)`

Comment: Ok. can you place a debugger in your `create.js.erb` and see if `flash` has any messages ?

Comment: I put a debugger. It raise the first time if my validation is ok or not ok.  But if I put another email in the input and send the form again without refreshing the page, the debugger don't raise whereas it respect or not the validation...

Comment: Can you reload the form, when the validation error is displayed everytime.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: When I send the form for the first time, I get the good respond from create.js.erb. But if I send the form a second time without reloading the page with the browser, my controller code is taken into account but not my create.js.erb code. For example, if i put an alert in the create.js.erb file, it doesn't pop the second time I send the form by clicking on the button again.

Comment: I have not tried this myself, in controller can you change `flash[:error] = @waiting_user.errors.full_messages` to `flash.now[:error] = @waiting_user.errors.full_messages`

Comment: It didn't make visible changes :s

Comment: Do you think it's possible to push it to a repo, I'm not sure what you're missing, would like to test it myself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I isolated the bug on this repo : https://github.com/Bonapara/simple_form_bug

Comment: The page to visit is `/concours` you either have to click on Rome or Barcelone to access the form.

Comment: Ok. I'll take a look at it.